# Prove that if $A=A^*$ then there exists an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors with real eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory, adjoint-operators, self-adjoint-operators

Suppose $F=\mathbb{R}$. Let $A: V\to V$ (where $V$ is a finite dimensional inner product space over $F$) so that $A=A^*$ ("self-adjoint"), then there exists an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors and eigenvalues are real.

---

(I come across the above problem when trying to understand how one could represent adjoint operators via their orthonormal base. I cannot find a complete proof in any books (from linear algebra to functional analysis)
I hope someone could help in providing a full proof.)

Thanks!

Comment: I suppose $A$ is self-adjoint?

Comment: in the case of a finite dimensional space over $\Bbb R$, self-adjoint is more commonly known as symmetric. This is then easy to google e.g. http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~peter/MATH10212/notes10

Comment: You say that as if there isn't a proof in that PDF.

Comment: It is hard to believe you did not find a proof of the Spectral Theorem, which is one of the most important theorems in linear algebra and functional analysis. What books did you check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $V$ is a finite-dimensional inner product space over the real numbers, and suppose $A$ is a symmetric linear operator on $V$. One way to find an eigenvector of $A$ is to minimize $F(v)=(Av,v)$ subject to the constraint that $\|v\|=1$. Such a minimum exists because you can use an orthonormal basis of $V$ and turn this into a minimization problem for a continuous function $F$ over the unit spherical shell in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, which is compact. A continuous function on a compact set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ has a minimum.

Suppose the minimum of $F$ on $S=\{ v \in V : \|v\|=1 \}$ is $\lambda$, and suppose $F(v_0)=\lambda$ for some unit vector $v_0$. Then you can show that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue and $(A-\lambda I)v_0=0$. This is because you must have
$$
              \lambda \le \frac{(Aw,w)}{(w,w)},\;\;\; w\ne 0 \\
               0 \le ((A-\lambda I)w,w),\;\;\; w \in V.
$$
That means $[x,y]=((A-\lambda I)x,y)$ has all of the properties of an inner product except that $[x,x]=0$ may occur even if $x \ne 0$. You can check that $[w,w] \ge 0$ because of the above, and it is easy to check that $[x,y]$ is linear in both $x$ and $y$. That's enough in order for the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to hold:
$$
                    |[x,y]| \le [x,x]^{1/2}[y,y]^{1/2}\\
       |((A-\lambda I)x,y)| \le ((A-\lambda I)x,x)^{1/2}((A-\lambda I)y,y)^{1/2}
$$
But you know that $[v_0,v_0]=((A-\lambda I)v_0,v_0)=0$ because of how $v_0$ was constructed. Therefore,
$$
                    ((A-\lambda I)v_0,y)=0, \;\;\; y \in V.
$$
This is true for all $y\in V$. Taking $y=(A-\lambda I)v_0$ gives $(A-\lambda I)v_0=0$.

Finally, you can use finite induction to get everything. That's because you can now reduce a symmetric operator $A$ on a subspace of one lower dimension. This is because $V' = \{ v : (v,v_0)=0 \}$ is invariant under $A$. To see why, suppose $v \perp v_0$. Then $(Av,v_0) = (v,Av_0)=(v,\lambda v_0)=\lambda(v,v_0)=0$. So $A : V'\rightarrow V'$ and the restriction $A'$ of $A$ to $V'$ is symmetric. Keep repeating the above procedure and eventually you end up with an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors of $V$.

Answer (score 6):

This is actually pretty easy. For simplicity, let us assume that $V = \mathbb R^n$ and that $A$ is a symmetric matrix. First, $A$ has without doubt complex eigenvalues because the characteristic polynomial has complex zeros. Then you see that each eigenvalue of $A$ must be real. Indeed, if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ with corresponding eigenvector $x\in\mathbb C^n$, then
$$
(\lambda - \overline{\lambda})\langle x,x\rangle = \langle\lambda x,x\rangle - \langle x,\lambda x\rangle = \langle Ax,x\rangle - \langle x,Ax\rangle = 0.
$$
Thus, $\operatorname{Im}\lambda = 0$ and $\lambda$ is real. Note that we have used the complex inner product here, i.e., $\langle x,y\rangle = \sum_i x_i\overline{y_i}$. It also follows that $x$ can be chosen to have only real entries (if $x$ is not real, choose $x + \overline{x}$ instead).

Now, let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $A$ with corresponding normalized eigenvector $x_1\in\mathbb R^n$. Then $\operatorname{span}\{x_1\}$ is invariant under $A$ and it also easily seen that also $(\operatorname{span}\{x_1\})^\perp$ is invariant under $A$. Now, restrict $A$ on the latter space and do the same thing again (which you can because the restriction is again symmetric/selfadjoint). Thus, you find an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors of $A$.